# Should the main function and main() be placed at the start or the end of the program?

Tags: python

I would like to know where to place my main function in python. I tried googling it but could not find any specific results. I don't think it really matters when you run the program but I was wondering if there was a proper format.

Comment: It's a matter of opinion - the only time is really matters if is you are working with a team and need to agree on how you want to do it within your team.

Comment: The usual convention is to put them at the end of the script. And of course you can't call `main` before you define it.

Answer (score 7):

There's no established convention, but I think that code is easier to read if the main logic is near the top of the file. I typically will define a `main` at the top, and then call it from the very bottom.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no established format for this.

Answer (score 2):

As far I know it's usually placed at the end. So as a practice, I always place it at the end as well.

```
import ...

class Application(object):
    ...

<other classes here>

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Application()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end is the convention. Possible dependencies that are called in main and defined **below** main won't work.